# Hiding Sharepoint Survey List fields

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, contenteditable, content-editor

I have a survey list. I need to hide a particular question by placing javascript in a content editor webpart. Can anybody give me the proper javascript code to hide the question in the survey list?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('MyQuestionID').style.display = 'none';
```

Though I'd suggest using JQuery and traversing up the dom from the element you want to hide, to hide the  thjat the element is contained within. In which case, load the JQuery JS file and use something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[title="MyQuestionTitle"]').parent().parent().css("display","none");    
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. with this code i can hide the textbox but people picker control is not hidden

Comment: Columns are rendered differently in the browser due to the type of data being presented. See answer below for a way to find the people picker control.

Answer (score 0):

The People Picker is a little trickier to pin down due to the way it is rendered in the browser, try something like this

```
var searchText = RegExp("FieldName=\"[YOUR PEOPLE PICKER NAME]\"", "gi");  
$("td.ms-formbody").each(function() {  
    if(searchText.test($(this).html())) 
    {  
        $(this).find("div[Title='People Picker']").css('display', 'none');
        return false;  
    }  
});
```